# Sistema de comentarios para noticias

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy desarrollando una pagina web con MySQL y PHP, dispongo de una sección de noticias donde cada una puede recibir comentarios. Estos comentarios también pueden ser respuesta a otro comentario. Para esto utilizo una tabla en la base de datos con la siguiente estructura

```
Create table comentario
(
   id int not null,
   id_comentario_padre int,
   texto varchar(255),
   fecha datetime,
   verificado tinyint
)
```

Ahora, como verán no estoy almacenando un nickname o algo por el estilo para el autor porque el problema que tengo es que a veces el autor sera un usuario registrado (en cuyo caso debería almacenar su id) y en otros casos el autor sera un visitante no logueado que podrá ingresar un alias para ese comentario. Esperaba que me pudieran ayudar con el diseño de la tabla comentario y como enfrentar esta duplicidad en los posibles valores de la columna del nickname

Comment: Hola Agustín, Bienvenido, te recomiendo que reformules un poco tu pregunta, ya que en este momento esta basada en opiniones, y no es algo permitido en StackOverflow en Español

Comment: Ya la edite, gracias por avisar.

Comment: No hay una _manera correcta_, en mi opinión, la pregunta sigue sin cumplir con las normas del sitio, pues pueden haber muchas maneras _correctas_ de diseñar la tabla, todo depende del punto de vista del autor y de los requerimientos generales del sistema de marras.